# Filtering out the unique values between 2 mongodb arrays using mongodb 3.4

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have 2 arrays:

```
"array1": [
    "057a7",
    "05790",
    "0575d",
    "0579f",
    "0576b",
    "05784",
    "05775"
]

"array2": [
    "0579f",
    "057a7",
    "05790",
    "05784",
    "0575d",
    "0576a",
    "0576b",
    "05775"
]
```

I have tried $setDifference, $setUnion and $setIntersection and these only output the elements that match.  I would like to output the one that does not ("0576a").  The examples I find in stack overflow only seem to show you how to output the duplicates and not the unique values.  The final output should be an array like so:

"final_array": ["0576a"]

Trying to do this in mongodb aggregation and not have to tap into mapReduce.

```
{
    "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "unique": {
            "$setDifference": [
                "$array2",
                "$array1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `$setDifference`

Comment: $setDifference doesn't seem to output the unique values.

Comment: `$setDifference : ["$array2","$array1"]` will return only `0576a`

Comment: getting back an empty array

Comment: Please post the query you've tried?

Comment: Got it to work @Saravana Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work for you:

```
db.collection('test').aggregate({
    $project: {
        "unique": {
            $concatArrays: [
                { $setDifference: [ "$array1", "$array2" ] },
                { $setDifference: [ "$array2", "$array1" ] }
            ]
        }
    }
})
```

The key thing to understand about [$setDifference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) is that the argument order matters since according to the documentation it...

> ...takes two sets and returns an array containing the elements that only
>   exist in the first set; i.e. performs a relative complement of the
>   second set relative to the first.

That's why you'll have to look at your arrays from both directions which will give you all unique elements and then you can simply merge the two results using [$concatArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/).